# Python: in a list, count sub-lists grouped by first element of these sub-lists

Tags: python

Given following list:

```
['21,*,1', '21,stuff,1', '21,*,10', '21,stuff,4', '21,*,1', '21,*,114', '21,stuff,1', 
 '28,*,37', '28,stuff,1', '28,*,4', '28,stuff,4', '28,*,4', '28,XXX,3', '28,stuff,1', '28,XXX,23', '28,XXX,87',
 '38,*,72', '38,stuff,9', '38,*,6', '38,stuff,32', '38,stuff,3', '38,stuff,3', '38,XXX,1', '38,*,23',
 '42,*,37', '42,XXX,1', '42,stuff,4']
```

I'd like to produce an array showing how many elements are contained in sub-lists (with first element in each sub-list being an id that'll always appear in ascending order: here 21, 28, 38 and 42): here we have 4 sub-lists starting respectively with 21, 28, 38 and 44, that contain 7, 9, 8 and 3 elements, so in this case a print of resulting array would be:
`[['21', 7], ['28', 9], ['38', 8], ['42', 3]]`

A beginner in Python, I'm looking for a simple and elegant way of doing this count...

Thanks a lot.
Sebino

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a custom key:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['21,*,1', '21,stuff,1', '21,*,10', '21,stuff,4', '21,*,1', '21,*,114', '21,stuff,1',
        '28,*,37', '28,stuff,1', '28,*,4', '28,stuff,4', '28,*,4', '28,XXX,3', '28,stuff,1', '28,XXX,23', '28,XXX,87',
        '38,*,72', '38,stuff,9', '38,*,6', '38,stuff,32', '38,stuff,3', '38,stuff,3', '38,XXX,1', '38,*,23',
        '42,*,37', '42,XXX,1', '42,stuff,4']
# ensure data is sorted so that the groups are contiguous
data.sort()

counts = []
for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x.split(',')[0]):  # use part before the first comma as the grouping criterion
    counts.append([k, len(list(g))])

print(counts)
```

Result:

```
[['21', 7], ['28', 9], ['38', 8], ['42', 3]]
```

Note: `counts` would be more usable as a dictionary IMO

Comment: it's going to perform lexicographical sorting. But I think OP would be needing "28,...." before "118,..."

Comment: I realise my ID appears between quotes, but these are numbers originally; and anyway functionally the order inside resulting array does not matter that much, as long as I have my element counts per ID...  
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

One liner approach using `collections.Counter`

```py
from collections import Counter

a = ['21,*,1', '21,stuff,1', '21,*,10', '21,stuff,4', '21,*,1', '21,*,114', '21,stuff,1', 
 '28,*,37', '28,stuff,1', '28,*,4', '28,stuff,4', '28,*,4', '28,XXX,3', '28,stuff,1', '28,XXX,23', '28,XXX,87',
 '38,*,72', '38,stuff,9', '38,*,6', '38,stuff,32', '38,stuff,3', '38,stuff,3', '38,XXX,1', '38,*,23',
 '42,*,37', '42,XXX,1', '42,stuff,4']

d = list(Counter(map(lambda f: f.split(',')[0], a)).items())

print(d)
```

Comment: Very impressive... Someone can pls explain step-by-step what this one-liner does? I guess I grasp what ".split(',')[0]" does but I don't understand this "lambda f:", then map, then Counter etc.
Thanks.

Comment: @Seb `lambda` is a python anonymous function, so replacing it with `def a(x): return x.split(",")[0]` is equivalent. And `map(function, iterable)` just applies a function for every element in a list. `Counter` is used for the string counting, returning a `dict`. But like your question said, You want a `list`, that

Comment: Continuing the the answer. You want a `list`, that's why its `list(Counter().items())`